# Remove all adjacent duplicates using loops

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to solve this problem. I have seen other solutions that involve lists and using recursion but I'm interested in learning how to solve this with loops and I can't seem to get the right output. 
*(i.e. no regular expressions, no tuples, no methods of string, etc.)*

```
input: caaabbbaacdddd
expected output:empty string

input:abbabd
expected output:bd
```

below is my code i have found other methods to solve this problem im just looking for the most basic solution for this.

```
answer = input("enter a string: ")
new_answer = ""

#while answer != new_answer:
if answer == "": 
    print("goodBye!")
    #break

p = ""

for c in answer:
    if p != c:
        new_answer += p
        p = c
    else:
         p = c  

print(new_answer)
```

the commented out part is to make the whole program loop through to verify thier is no more duplicates.

Comment: What happens when you run your code? Does it give the correct output? If not how does the output differ from what you want? I suggest that you read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on how to debug your code.

Comment: well the issue im having with my code is it still repeats the varible even if it was marked as a duplicate. so i feel like im missing a key peice to it but i cant figure it out  @Code-Apprentice

Comment: Debugging is an important skill to learn, at least as important as writing code. The link I gave in my first comment has some great tips to get you started.

Comment: i feel the problem with my code lies in the for statement. im not sure if its missing a argument

Answer (score 0):

The simplest loop-based solution would be:

```
result = ""
for i in answer:
    if result == "" or result[-1] != i:
        result += i
```

You could also use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) which does what you're looking for:

```
print("".join([i for i in map(lambda x: x[0], itertools.groupby(answer))])
```

Comment: it does but im specfially looking for the answer in the most basic way and by using loops

Comment: Added a loop-based approach.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are just comparing the current character with the immediate previous character. You can use the `in` operator:

```
if char in String
```

for all 26 characters

You could also make a dictionary for all 26 characters if you can use that (since you are only using loops)

Answer (score 0):

Try this! Only issue in your logic is that you are not removibg the character which is being repeated once its added tk the new_answer.

```
count = 0
for c in answer:
    if p != c:
        new_answer += p
        p = c
    else:
        new_answer = new_answer.replace(c,””,count)
        p = c  
    count += 1
print(new_answer)
```

Simplifying it even more without replace function:

```
count = 0
for c in answer:
    if p != c:
        new_answer += p
        p = c
    else:
        if count == 0:
             new_answer =“”
        else:
             new_answer=new_answer[:count-1]
             count -=1
        p = c  
     count += 1
print(new_answer)
```

Comment: could you explain the part when you use the .replace function

Comment: If previous char is equal to current char then i am removing the previous char from the new_answer. Replace function removes that char and substitutes with “” in its place. Also, since i want to only remove that character once at a specific location, that location information is provided by count.

Comment: would their be a way of simpliying it even more without using the replace function? @Kdulam

Comment: Edited my answer to simplify without replace function.

Comment: `if count =0:` is not valid python

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this with javascript ( i know it's not python, but same logic):

```
let answer = 'acacbascsacasceoidfewfje';
for(i=0;i<answer.length;i++){
         if(obj[answer.substr(i,1)] === undefined){
              obj[answer.substr(i,1)] = 1
         }else{
              obj[answer.substr(i,1)]++;
         }
    }

    JSON.stringify(obj)
```

**Results:**

> "{"a":4,"c":4,"b":1,"s":2,"e":2,"o":1,"i":1,"d":1,"f":1,"w":1,"j":1}"

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class RemoveAdjacentDuplicates {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(removeDuplicates("abbabd"));
        }

         public static String removeDuplicates(String S) {
             char[] stack = new char[S.length()];

             int i = 0;

             for(int j = 0 ; j < S.length() ; j++) {

                 char currentChar = S.charAt(j);
                 if(i > 0 && stack[i-1] == currentChar) {
                     i--;
                 }else {
                     stack[i] = currentChar;
                     i++;
                 }

             }
             return new String(stack , 0 , i);
         }

    }
```

***Results of the program are :***

```
    input: caaabbbaacdddd
    output:empty string

    input:abbabd
    output:bd
```